# Cannot apply the css

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to change the CSS of a specific `div` `(.cropper)` inside a component called `image-cropper` but I don't know why it's not working.

Here an image of the `div`.

[image]

And here is the CSS I tried to use to access the selected div:

```
    image-cropper {
     div {
      .cropper {
       border-radius: 50%;
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of if, it seems that it is one more div deep. Also try adding `!important;` at the end, to override component css.

```css
image-cropper > div > div.cropper {
border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: It makes total sense but it didn't work, this is actually one of my biggest doubts in css, because the path you used makes sense but doesn't access it anyway.

Comment: Then please reproduce minimum example of the problem online (e.g stackblitz) so we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
image-cropper div .cropper { border-radius: 50% !important; }
```

Use this CSS & check.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible with SASS.

```
image-cropper
  > div
    > .cropper border-radius: 50%;
```

Or

```
image-cropper{
  div{
    .cropper{
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

Or in CSS you can only do like this:

```
image-cropper > div > .cropper{
   Border-radius: 50%;
}
```